# ASP.NET Sort Each Gridview in Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a GridView control that loads on a page and acts as a nest for other GridViews. Each child GridView contains the same columns and datatypes and so I want the user to be able to click a LinkButton to sort each of these GridViews by a specified sort expression.
Here is the code I have so far, which does not work. It just goes to PostBack but returns the data in the same order.

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        if (c.ID == "dgvResults")
        {
            GridView s = (GridView)c;
            DataTable dataTable = s.DataSource as DataTable;

            if (dataTable != null)
            {
                DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
                dataView.Sort = "OEN ASC";

                s.DataSource = dataView;
                s.DataBind();
            }


        }
    }
```

**Edit 1:** I discovered that the DataSource is no longer bound on PostBack, so I have to store the GridView DataSource as a DataTable in a Session variable. Now I can't get that working.

**Edit 2:** I've attempted to store the Gridview.DataSource on both DataBinding and DataBound events of my child GridViews, but they never get stored in either case. When I try to call them up again in the code above, the session variable that should contain the Datatable does not exist.

Here is the code I've put in to store the DataTable:

```
// The variable 's' represents the GridView control that triggered the DataBinding event
Session["dtResults"] = s.DataSource as DataTable;

// The code below is how I call the Session variable that I set earlier in the DataBinding event
if (Session["dtResults"] != null) 
{
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)Session["dtResults"];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled `viewstate` for gridview and tried?

Comment: ViewState was already enabled, and I also tried storing the datatable in a ViewState[] variable. I might have to go the route of ditching the GridView nest and group my data stored in a single GridView control.

Answer (score 0):

***This might not be the right way to close up this question, but I've settled for this method and it works for me.***

The real problem was that my `GridViews` were attached to a bunch of `DropDownList` controls which fed the parameter values to my `DataSources` upon PostBack. If I were limited to 1 `GridView` only, then I could have stored it's `DataTable` in  `ViewState`, but because I'm dealing with a nest of dynamically populated `GridViews`, this was not possible (as far as I could get working).

So, instead of iterating through each `GridView` in the nest, I just set up one more `DropDownList`, this one containing a list of the field names that match the GridViews' and the user can then choose from the list on which field they want to order the data. Then the value of this list is passed by `PostBack` to the `DataSource`'s stored procedure, which in turn deals with the parameter internally.

The nice thing about doing it this way is the user still has the option to sort each `GridView` individually if they want to instead.